# webpack script in package.json

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server, package.json

I have a question regarding the `script` property in `package.json` of my app. If I type `npm start`, the app gets compiled successfully. And it seems that by typing the above command, `www` file starts running.

However, if I type `npm webpack`, nothing happens. I have a react/express app. And the server runs on `localhost:3000` on `npm start`. I want to know, is webpack serving both react and express? I am able to send requests from the client to the server and show the result on the client-side. I just wanted to know how things are working.

```js
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon ./bin/www",
    "webpack": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

for other scripts than "start", you have to type npm run [scriptname].
in your case: `npm run webpack`